# aws cloudfront certificate logic for subdomain and wildcards

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have cloudront with `admin-dev.example.com` and `www.admin-dev.example.com` alternative names, why verified certificate with domain name `*.example.com` not working when i'm trying to attach? throws an error:

```
The certificate that is attached to your distribution doesn't cover the alternate domain name (CNAME) that you're trying to add. For more details, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-requirements
```

But when i have `admin.dev.example.com` and `www.admin.dev.example.com` and `*.dev.example.com` certificate it's working fine

p.s. domains with www is alternative domain names

p.p.s certificates don't have alternative domain names